# Work Off ActiveJob Queue Programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

With `DelayedJob`, it's possible to instantiate a worker to complete jobs programmatically:

```
Delayed::Worker.new.work_off # => [num_succesess, num_failures]
```

Does ActiveJob provide any interface for doing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently not if it is planned for the future? I don't know. ActiveJob currently provide only interface for creating new job and perform it on the background in very limited way.

ActiveJob currently provide only:

- Create new job and perform it in the background process
- Specify name of the queue which have to be used
- Ability to retry job (but you have to specify conditions and calculate how much time it should wait before it will be processed again)
- Nice interface for sending emails via queue

It doesn't provide:

- any nice API to eg. calculate number of iteration and work with it in some way (it is planed for next version probably, but it still be quite manual https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/core.rb#L70)
- you also cannot use any of the hook methods in delayed_job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks
- or specify any of the delayed_job parameters in the job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs (e.g. `max_attempts`, `max_run_time` and so on.

It is really limited right now, but I am interested where this gem goes and how it will evolve.

I hope this helps a bit.